# How to write an equivalent RankedMax function in Mma 7.0

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I need to use something equivalent to RankedMax in Mma 8.0, but I only have version 7.0. Is this something doable, or it has to be done at the kernel/implementation level?

Many thanks!

Comment: Just FYI, AFAIK Licenses for v8 are compatible with v7. That means you may install v8 in the same machine and the licenses are going to be shared. The only caveat is that you'll not be able to enjoy the new v8 features that require Internet connectivity (but anyway you don't have those right now)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [more information section](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RankedMax.html) of the 8.0 help page for `RankedMax`, the function is equivalent to this:

```
RankedMax[list_, 1] := Max[list]
RankedMax[list_, n_] /; n == Length@list := Min[list]
RankedMax[list_, n_] := Module[{m=Length@list}, Quantile[list, (m - n + 1) / m]]
```

The `Quantile` function is available in 7.0.